# Adding lightning component to page Error : Unable to parse JSON response

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am having an issue adding my lightning component onto my opportunity page for testing the error is

> Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem
>   continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID
>   shown here and any other related details. Unable to parse JSON
>   response

my component is basic consisting of my .cmp, .js and my controller listed below:

**.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller ="AddProductsController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="opportunity" type="Opportunity"/>
<aura:attribute name="oppId" type="String" default="{!v.recordId}"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <ui:button label="Card Not Present" press="{!c.AddCNP}"/>
    <li></li>
    <ui:button label="Card Present" press="{!c.AddCP}"/>
    <li></li>
    <ui:button label="Eccomerce" press="{!c.AddECOM}"/>
    <h1>{!v.oppId}</h1>
</aura:component>
```

**.js**

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getOpp");
    action.setParams({
        "oppId": component.get("v.recordId")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
    var state = a.getState();
    if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        component.set("v.opportunity", a.getReturnValue());
    }
        else{
            console.log('Error init function' + state);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

AddCNP : function(component, event, helper) {
    List<OpportunityLineItem> Oli = List<OpportunityLineItem>();
},
AddCP : function(component, event, helper) {
    List<OpportunityLineItem> Oli = List<OpportunityLineItem>();
},
AddECOM : function(component, event, helper) {
    List<OpportunityLineItem> Oli = List<OpportunityLineItem>();
}
})
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class AddProductsController {
 @AuraEnabled
public static Opportunity getOpp(Id oppId){
    return([Select id, Name
                            From Opportunity Where id=:oppId]);
}

}
```

As far as I am aware I have implemented it correctly and the opportunity object just be being parsed onto the view. Any ideas?

Comment: See what `a.getReturnValue()` is holding in the setCallback before setting its value to opportunity. May be its not a valid.

Comment: What's quickest way to test for that just tried logging ton console but component doesn't run

Comment: Also your method(AddCNP, AddCP & AddECOM  ) definitions are wrong. JS controller can not take list of specific type like apex. Remove them for once and try.

Comment: If you still need to see the response add `console.log(JSON.stringify(a.getReturnValue()))` and check the JavaScript console for what is output. You can check the request somewhat similarly by adding `console.log(JSON.stringify(action.getParams()))` before the request is enqueued. Also turn on server side logging to see if anything useful is reported there.

Comment: Didn't quite understand "works not thanks so much", but I guess I helped, so I am glad. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting an answer just so the thread can be closed.

```
List<OpportunityLineItem> Oli = List<OpportunityLineItem>();
```

is not the appropiate way of declaring a list of type OpportunityLineItem in JavaScript.

Your Javascript code doesn't know what is OpportunityLineItem, so for JS, its just an array to which you can put any one kind of items.

So declare an array like this:

```
var Oli = [];
```

then push items into it:

```
Oli.push(oliItem);
```